# Overflow Error VBA: Multiplying & Dividing Percentage

Tags: vba, excel

I have a question about getting an overflow error when multiplying values of different columns.

The idea is simple, all I want is to perform some basic Math. To give an example
 `IF(Cells(i,13).Value + Cells(i,15).Value)) * 60  = 828000.00%,` then when Cells(i,6) , which equals 8708.03, is divided by 828000.00% the result should be approximately 1.05 / 105%. However, because of the overflow error, I can't perform this rather straightforward calculation. Any ideas on how I could fix this?

```
wb1.Sheets("Total").Cells(i, 8).Value = 
wb1.Sheets("Total").Cells(i, 6).Value / (wb1.Sheets("Total").Cells(i,13).Value + wb1.Sheets("Total").Cells(i,15).Value)* 60)
```

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to give a definitive answer, can you alter it to also show the value of `Cells(i,15)`

Comment: Is it possible, that the overflow is in `i` while performing this on a lot of rows with an integer?

Comment: @GaryEvans Sorry about that, it's a spreadsheet of over 25000 values, so I didn't add it in. I'll definitely try to be more clear next time though!

Comment: @Jochen I figured it out! Thank you both for the quick replies. Btw, I was sure it wasn't the `i` because I used that variable for a lot of other things and they all worked, but your explanation would be a way more satisfying solution than what it actually is haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an incredibly silly mistake that I somehow spent forever on. But turns out, the problem was that there was one sneaky row hiding in the spreadsheet with a value of 0, causing an "Overflow" error when I tried to divide. Thanks for the edit & help though! :)

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. If its possible can mark this as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The chances of an overflow can be reduced by breaking the math down into sections.

Your math can be expressed as below (simply shortened for easier reading): -

Cell(*8*) = Cell(*6*) / (Cell(*13*) + Cell(*15*))* 60)

To break the math down do it over to lines that share the work: -

Cell(*8*) = (Cell(*13*) + Cell(*15*))* 60

Cell(*8*) = Cell(*6*) / (Cell(*8*)